# Domain restrictions in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, iis

Our arcgis server just got updated to 10.1. All the configurations are done and it is now running properly. But we still need to restrict explicit access to the REST services and only localhost(127.0.0.1) to have access to the REST services.

We have done it in 9.3 by adding an allow entry for localhost on the ArcGIS web app in IIS under the IP Address and Domain Restrictions. Also we set the Feature settings to deny all unspecified clients.

We did the same thing to 10.1 but we can still make explicit calls to the arcgis REST services through other PC.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Did you install web adapter at your end ?

Comment: may be helpful for you  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000041q000000

Comment: Hi Sunil, the webadaptor was installed but we never configured it. Since the services were working without configuring it. Is the web adaptor the one we need to restrict access by ip or domain?

Comment: Hi guys, we finally fixed the issue. turns out there was an explicit rule in our firewall that allows any connection to our arcgis server through 6080 port that seems to be overriding the IIS restrictions. Once we modified the rule to only allow the local ip to access the server, the access from different ip's are not working anymore. Thanks for your advice Sunil. appreciate it :D

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please put this in answer section and mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we finally fixed the issue. turns out there was an explicit rule in our firewall that allows any connection to our arcgis server through 6080 port that seems to be overriding the IIS restrictions. Once we modified the rule to only allow the local ip to access the server, the access from different ip's are not working anymore. Thanks for your advice Sunil. appreciate it :D